# Redis 7 Offline Installation Best Practices

Tags: package-management, redis

Im looking to install the latest Redis version on Ubuntu 18 and found the deb packages in this link : [https://launchpad.net/~redislabs/+archive/ubuntu/redis/+build/25404032](https://launchpad.net/%7Eredislabs/+archive/ubuntu/redis/+build/25404032) which look legitimate. Is it safe to use these packages for a production environment ? Or the preferred recommended way is to build from source and have a deb package created from that build ? In my case cannot use apt as this will be an offline installation.

In this case the package is 7.0.7 so yeah it might not make sense to go for this release as it was just released but the question still stands.

Also one question that might sound silly, what would the rl1 mean in the package name, example : 7.0.7-1rl1~bionic1 ?

Comment: The package you linked is for 18.04 & not the *snap* based 18  (18 & 18.04 are different Ubuntu products, with *year* format (18) being reserved for *snap* only products since 2016).

Comment: The link you provided is to a *Personal Package Archive*, meaning all security checks are whatever you perform yourself including if you trust the source ([*Redis Lab*](https://launchpad.net/~redislabs-team) is a person in this case). Packages can follow whichever naming strategy they wish to (*within a team of course, but there won't be much disagreement with a single member team*) so you may need to ask the packager for what they mean by *rl1*.

Comment: @guiverc thank you for the info , understood. Will check it out.